# aws s3 component access from cloudfront accessdenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have put up a website https://somesite.org, if user access the link, then click on "incomeTax", it is working fine and https://somesite.org/incomeTax is the url on browser. However, if user tries to refresh the url, meaning as if user directly access https://somesite.org/incomeTax, it gives accessdenied error. Anyone knows why?

Directly access the S3 bucket is fine, using http://somesite.org.s3-website.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/incomeTax. However, when using https and cloud front url, it is not working.
Tried referer related fix, not working either.

Comment: direct s3 endpoint is working fine? also, S3 static web hosting setting, both `Error document` and `Index document` pointing to home page , let's say `index.html` ?

Comment: What is the Bucket Policy associated with the Amazon S3 bucket? Does it mention `referer`?  Are you saying that this website is being served by CloudFront, backed by an S3 bucket?

Comment: Directly access the S3 bucket is fine, using http://investorcare.org.s3-website.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/incomeTax. However, when using https and cloud front url, it is not working. Tried referer related fix, not working either.

Answer (score 0):

followed https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef#cf55

For "Origin Domain Name", instead of using the drop down of S3 bucket, copy-and-paste your S3 URL with region info, like .s3-.amazonaws.com.

Then I start to get "404 Not found, Code: NoSuchKey".
Solution is not intuitive but to my surprise it works: configure Cloudfront error handler (error page) for both 403 and 404 to return index.html with a 200 OK status.

I thought it will redirect to root index.html, but actually it returns to the actual path that I wanted!